# SQL Proc Modification Question

Tags: .net, t-sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, paging

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spGetMessages]
    @lastRow int
AS
BEGIN
    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    DECLARE @StartRow INT,@EndRow INT
    SELECT @StartRow = (@lastRow + 1), @EndRow = (@lastRow + 6)

;WITH cte AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY
        CASE WHEN @sort = 'votes1' THEN m.votes END DESC,
        CASE WHEN @sort = 'votes2' THEN m.votes END ASC,
        CASE WHEN @sort = 'age1' THEN datediff(minute,m.timestamp, getdate()) END ASC,
        CASE WHEN @sort = 'age2' THEN datediff(minute,m.timestamp, getdate()) END DESC
      ) AS rows,
      m.message,
      m.messageId
    FROM
      tblMessages m
    WHERE
      m.deleted != 1
      )
     SELECT * 
     FROM cte WHERE ROWS BETWEEN @StartRow AND @EndRow
    ORDER BY rows
END
```

So this proc gets me a bunch of messages, but passing in the last row value so I can implement paging, and a 'load more' functionality on the front end.

If the proc returns less than 6 messages, I can disable 'load more' obviously, if it returns 6 messages however, I don't know if there's more in the database, or that those were the last 6 messages.

My thought was that if I passed back another `DataTable` containing either `true` or `false` that represented if there were more than these 6 messages left in the database using the last row id, I could use this flag to enable/disable the 'load more' button. Is this a good idea? If not, what's a better plan?

If so, how would I modify this proc to pass that flag back?

Comment: How about returning the total number of records via a parameter? Then you can calculate how many pages you have, too

Comment: Total number of records LEFT, based off the last rowId, is what I'm aiming for I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have several procs like this.  The easy way was to add an additional column in the output called "TotalCount" which returned a count of all rows.

In your case it would look like:

```
;WITH cte AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY
        CASE WHEN @sort = 'votes1' THEN m.votes END DESC,
        CASE WHEN @sort = 'votes2' THEN m.votes END ASC,
        CASE WHEN @sort = 'age1' THEN datediff(minute,m.timestamp, getdate()) END ASC,
        CASE WHEN @sort = 'age2' THEN datediff(minute,m.timestamp, getdate()) END DESC      ) AS rows,
            m.message, m.messageId,
        TotalCount = COUNT(m.Id) OVER ( PARTITION BY NULL)
    FROM tblMessages m
    WHERE m.deleted != 1
)
SELECT *
FROM cte 
WHERE ROWS BETWEEN @StartRow AND @EndRow
ORDER BY rows
```

I'm assuming the tblMessages has a column called Id.  The point is to simply count the unique id's in that table.

We did it this way so we wouldn't have to run 2 queries.  Of course, depending on the size of data this could have a possible performance impact.  So test both ways.

======
BTW, one that thing comes to mind.  You might consider not using prefixes (like "tbl" and "sp")  That's a very outdated way of doing things and generally completely unnecessary.

Comment: Whats this actually a row count of? the amount left?

Comment: @slandau: It's a count of ALL matching records based on your where clause, even the ones that aren't in the actual result set.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an output parameter to send back the information you need - maybe the total row count so that you can define the number of pages to paginate against? You just add the OUTPUT parameter to the proc declaration:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spGetMessages]
    @lastRow int,
    @yourFlagHere BIT OUTPUT
```

I added BIT to support your binary validation, but you can use several other types. For more info, check [Returning Data by Using OUTPUT Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187004.aspx). You would then assign the value to the output parameter by calling the proc with

```
EXEC dbo.spGetMessages @lastRowYouDefined, @yourFlagHere OUTPUT
```

Your `@yourFlagHere` var will have the value defined from within the procedure.